# Redireccionamiento de login en nodejs con express

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, handlebars.js

Estoy iniciando con node y express, me gustaría que me puedan ayudar con problema de re-direccionamiento después de login, no entiendo que pudiera estar haciendo mal.

El código que tengo escrito esta de la siguiente forma:

Este es el archivo index de ruteo

```
router.get('/signIn', function(req, res) {
res.redirect('/home')
})
```

El scritp del ciente esta asi,

```
fetch('/api/signIn', {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    headers: {
   'Accept': 'application/json',
   'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
   },
    body: formBody

})
```

De antemano les agradezco cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Comment: Hola Andy, el tema es que no me envia ningun error, solo no hace nada, pero si pasa por esa instruccion porque puse un console.log('paso') por debajo del redirect. 
 
Veras cuando uso el metodo get y pego la url en el navegador hace el redireccionamiento sin problema localhost:3001/api/signIn, el problema viene cuando lo hago desde el boton en el hmtl que llamo a el metodo post para enviar el cuerpo del formulario. En ese caso ya no hace nada, no se si haya que haya que renderizar algo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No puedes transformar una petición AJAX en una normal para poder hacer una redirección. En tu petición estás diciendo que vas a aceptar un JSON:

```
'Accept': 'application/json',
```

Lo que puedes es:

- Realizar una petición HTTP normal
- Realizar la redirección en el cliente

Si estás usando AJAX para obtener una respuesta JSON, quizás del resultado del login, etc., envía una bandera que indique el estado del proceso o, en si usas un token, puedes comprobar que este exista en la respuesta:

```
const response = await fetch('/api/signIn', {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    headers: {
   'Accept': 'application/json',
   'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
   },
   body: formBody
}).then(res => res.json());

if (response.<success|token>) {
  // login exitoso, <guardar token si existe alguno> redireccionar
  location.assign('/home');
}
```

**Nota:** si no usas Babel, usar otro `.then` en lugar de `await` y hacer el condicional dentro.

Comment: Hola Gustavo, gracias por tu respuesta, como bien lo mencionas usare json web token, y guardare algunos datos propios del usuario en el local storage, con esto que tu comentas entonces el redireccionamiento quedaria en el lado del cliente y no en el server como se se muestra aqui?                                                                                                                         router.post('/signIn', function(req, res) {
res.redirect('/home')
})

Comment: Sería una redirección en el lado cliente que luego devolverá una respuesta el controlador de `/home`.